# wpf: add style to ComboBoxItem trough binding

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, styles

I've a `ComboBox` and a `Style` for the items.  The style is defined by using `Style.Triggers` in this way:

```
  <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BlueViolet"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

In order to embed this `Style` I would write next :

```
<ComboBox>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="xxxx" Tag="true"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="yyyy" Tag="false"/>
</ComboBox>
```

but how I can embed this `Style` in case I use `DataContext` binding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the triggers should still work, irrespective of whether you set the value of Tag manually or via Binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a style setter to the ComboBox's Resources:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding SomeValue}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

Comment: I got lost...

I have some list with values were each value actually binded to the ComboBoxItem. 
as i said, the binding is done by combo.DataContext = list...

where do i put the tag property ?

Thanks

Comment: @user301639 Is the Tag value part of your list of values? If so, this bit of code will take each ComboBoxItem inside the ComboBox and create a binding for the Tag. If you are simply trying to alternate the Style for every other row, you are better off setting your ComboBox's `AlternationCount` to 2 and building your trigger based on `AlternationIndex`

Comment: Thanks for idea, found some example in msdn site, solved my problem :)